# Windows Phone 8.1 RT - Saving and loading page state

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have 3 pages: first - MainPage, second - PivotPage, and third - SimplePage. I want to save the PivotPage state when I'm navigate to SimplePage and load it when go back. I tried to use NavigationHelper class but it also saves and load PivotPage state when I back from PivotPage to MainPage and then navigate to PivotPage again, which is not desirable. Does anyone can help me handle this?

**EDIT:**

I have 4 cases:

1. page with hub
2. page with pivot
3. page with pivot with lists
4. page with list

How to save and load position of selected item there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do what you want, but maybe simple flag would be sufficient (hence loading the state is fired in `OnNavigatedTo`):

```
// provide a flag 
private bool ifLoadData = false;

// set the flag before state is loaded
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    ifLoadData = e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back;
    // rest of the code

// then in LoadState just check if you want your data to be loaded
private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    if (ifLoadData)
    {
       // load data
```

Comment: The thing is that I want to load a position of item in listview in right pivotitem.

Comment: @user3853371 Can you better describe/edit your question? The code above should help to load stored data via *NavigationHelper*, you can store position, pivotitem, depending on what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is what you need

add this to your constructor

```
    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```

Comment: This saves state of page and load it every time when you back to it and also when you navigate to again, which is desirable.

Comment: With the mix of Romasz answer, it is useful.